# Python - String Reverse, Print After Every Change

Tags: python, string, input, reverse

I need user to enter some text, later this text should be reversed.
But while reversing, I need to print every step, i really don't know how it works, how it reverses.

If user enters - stack, in the end I need to get `kcats`, but before I need to also print all the steps for example if it starts from the first and the last letters, first step should be like - `ktacs` and continue like that.

I have some kind of a code :

```
input_string = input("\n Please Enter Text To Reverse - ")
for i in input_string:
    print(input_string[::-1])
```

It does a reverse, but I can't print out step by step. Any help please ?

Comment: you can not print each step of reversing when you are using slicing `input_string[::-1]` you need to make own function and add print statements on every desired step

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
txt = "hello world"
l = len(txt)
for n in range(1, l//2+1):
    print txt[-n:][::-1] + txt[n:-n] + txt[:n][::-1] # reversed end + middle + reversed start
```

you can also use this (but I find it less readable):

```
print txt[l-1:-n-1:-1] + txt[n:-n] + txt[n-1:None:-1]
```

Comment: Strings are not mutable: the reversal cannot be conducted in place the way you are suggesting

Comment: @ReblochonMasque well this code works here so not sure what you mean. I'm not mutating any string... just printing all 'steps' as asked by OP.

Comment: Your code is illustrating the swapping of pairs of elements of a string, in place. It can't happen that way with strings.

Comment: Ok so what? I don't see any mention in OP's question that things would have to happen in place (which is impossible as you say).

Comment: Actually it works pretty well in my situation, i already tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: So your answer is incorrect, this is not how strings are reversed... The argument that "it works so what" is not very brilliant. No, the OP did not mention "in place", you proposed an "in place process".

Comment: 1- Strings aren't (and can't be) swapped at all (as in place). 2- I never mentioned 'in place' nor did OP, you are the one hallucinating over it 3- yes if it solves OP's question what is your problem? 4- "your answer is incorrect" is a brilliant argument indeed

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
   input_string = input("\n Please Enter Text To Reverse - ")
   i_string = input_string.split(" ")
   length = len(i_string)

   for i in range(len(i_string)-1,-1,-1):
      print(i_string[i])
   print(i_string[::-1])
```

Hopefully This would help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print every step then you can use recursive approach:

The beauty of Recursion :

```
string_='stack'

def recursion_reverse(string_1):
    if not string_1:
        return ""
    else:
        front_part=recursion_reverse(string_1[1:])
        back_part=string_1[0]
        print(front_part+back_part + string_[:-len(string_1)])


    return front_part+back_part[0]

print(recursion_reverse(string_))
```

output:

```
kstac
kcsta
kcast
kcats
kcats
kcats
```